# Nunit Test Ordering

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

Is there any way we can create ordered list from nunit,

there are multiple test-cases which need to be run multiple times but not in sequence.

```
For Example : 
1) TestCase A 
2) TestCase B
3) TestCase C
4) TestCase B
```

How can I achieve it through N-Unit (C#)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to have the order in which tests are executed to have an effect. They should be independent.

Comment: Yeah , I know but there must be options still to keep it going , are there any?

Comment: Yes there are, in the linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054935/563532 in particular). I just noticed `TestCase B` is repeated, so it's not necessarily a duplicate. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can ordering accept multiple values,how can I make TestCase B called twice?

Answer (score -1):

you can use it  like below

```
 [Test, Order(1)]
 [Test, Order(2)]
 [Test, Order(3)]
```

Thank you!!