# Run selenium NUnit tests in specific order

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, nunit

I have a selenium project written with NUnit in C# .NET 6. I have a folder called '**Tests**' where there are multiple sub folders and each folder has a lot of classes. Each class has only one **Test** method. The reason for this is for structuring the project and each class represents one process in the software I'm testing. However, some processes need to be run after some other processes have already ran.

My question is; is there any way to run the classes in a specific order I want? I have tried using

```
dotnet test --filter
```

However this did not work. I also tried using NUnit's

```
Order
```

attribute but this works only when a class has multiple test methods.

Comment: Take a look on this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078678/12888976

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NUnit Test Run Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078658/nunit-test-run-order)

Comment: I already had a look at these. Unfortunately they did not solve my problem. I want to be able to order the tests at a global level (i.e order all different test classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Order attribute may be placed on a class or a method. From the NUnit docs:

> The OrderAttribute may be placed on a test method or fixture to specify the order in which tests are run within the fixture ***or other suite*** in which they are contained.

The bold italics in the citation are mine. In your case, the "other suite" containing the fixture class is the namespace in which it is defined.

There is no "global" ordering facility, but if all your tests are in the same namespace, using the `OrderAttribute` on the fixtures will cause them to run in the order you specify. If it doesn't interfere with any other use of the namespaces you might consider putting them all in one namespace.

A couple of notes:

1. The `OrderAttribute` specifies the order in which the tests start. If you run tests in parallel, multiple tests may run at the same time.
2. It's not advisable to have the tests depend on one another in most cases.
3. There are lots of reasons **not** to control the order of tests, which are covered in the answers quoted by other folks. I'm just answering the specific "how-to" question you posed.